# Error during NER Tagger compilation

Tags: theano

I am new to Python, I am conducting my MS research in deep learning. I was trying to run the NER Tagger provided by https://github.com/glample/tagger in Anaconda Prompt and cmd but I got the following error on Windows 7 32 bit-python 2.7 with numpy and theano installed.

Sorry for pasting such a long error but I am unable to fix this.

```
00878 {
00879 // save references to outputs prior to updating storage containers
00880 assert (self->n_output_vars >= self->n_updates);
00881 Py_DECREF(rval);
00882 rval = PyList_New(self->n_output_vars);
00883 for (int i = 0; i < (self->n_output_vars); ++i)
00884 {
00885 Py_ssize_t src = self->output_vars[i];
00886 PyObject * item = PyList_GetItem(self->var_value_cells[src
], 0);
00887 if ((output_subset == NULL || output_subset[i]) &&
00888 self->var_computed[src] != 1)
00889 {
00890 err = 1;
00891 PyErr_Format(PyExc_AssertionError,
00892 "The compute map of output %d should cont
ain "
00893 "1 at the end of execution, not %d.",
00894 i, self->var_computed[src]);
00895 break;
00896 }
00897 Py_INCREF(item);
00898 PyList_SetItem(rval, i, item);
00899 }
00900 }
00901
00902 if (!err)
00903 {
00904 // Update the inputs that have an update rule
00905 for (int i = 0; i < self->n_updates; ++i)
00906 {
00907 PyObject* tmp = PyList_GetItem(rval, self->n_output_vars -
self->n_updates + i);
00908 Py_INCREF(tmp);
00909 Py_ssize_t dst = self->update_storage[i];
00910 PyList_SetItem(self->var_value_cells[dst], 0, tmp);
00911 }
00912 }
00913 }
00914
00915 /*
00916 Clear everything that is left and not an output. This is needed
00917 for lazy evaluation since the current GC algo is too conservative
00918 with lazy graphs.
00919 /
00920 if (self->allow_gc && !err)
00921 {
00922 for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < self->n_vars; ++i)
00923 {
00924 int do_cleanup = 1;
00925 if (!self->var_has_owner[i] || !self->var_computed[i])
00926 continue;
00927 for (int j = 0; j < self->n_output_vars; ++j)
00928 {
00929 if (i == self->output_vars[j])
00930 {
00931 do_cleanup = 0;
00932 break;
00933 }
00934 }
00935 if (!do_cleanup)
00936 continue;
00937 Py_INCREF(Py_None);
00938 PyList_SetItem(self->var_value_cells[i], 0, Py_None);
00939 }
00940 }
00941 if (output_subset != NULL)
00942 free(output_subset);
00943
00944 Py_DECREF(one);
00945 Py_DECREF(zero);
00946 if (err)
00947 {
00948 Py_DECREF(rval);
00949 return NULL;
00950 }
00951 return rval;
00952 }
00953
00954 #if 0
00955 static PyMethodDef CLazyLinker_methods[] = {
00956 {
00957 //"name", (PyCFunction)CLazyLinker_accept, METH_VARARGS, "Return t
he name, combining the first and last name"
00958 },
00959 {NULL} / Sentinel /
00960 };
00961 #endif
00962
00963
00964 static PyObject *
00965 CLazyLinker_get_allow_gc(CLazyLinker self, void closure)
00966 {
00967 return PyBool_FromLong(self->allow_gc);
00968 }
00969
00970 static int
00971 CLazyLinker_set_allow_gc(CLazyLinker self, PyObject value, void closu
re)
00972 {
00973 if(!PyBool_Check(value))
00974 return -1;
00975
00976 if (value == Py_True)
00977 self->allow_gc = true;
00978 else
00979 self->allow_gc = false;
00980 return 0;
00981 }
00982
00983 static PyGetSetDef CLazyLinker_getset[] = {
00984 {(char)"allow_gc",
00985 (getter)CLazyLinker_get_allow_gc,
00986 (setter)CLazyLinker_set_allow_gc,
00987 (char)"do this function support allow_gc",
00988 NULL},
00989 {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL} / Sentinel /
00990 };
00991 static PyMemberDef CLazyLinker_members[] = {
00992 {(char)"nodes", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(CLazyLinker, nodes), 0,
00993 (char)"list of nodes"},
00994 {(char)"thunks", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(CLazyLinker, thunks), 0,
00995 (char)"list of thunks in program"},
00996 {(char*)"call_counts", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(CLazyLinker, call_count
s), 0,
00997 (char*)"number of calls of each thunk"},
00998 {(char*)"call_times", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(CLazyLinker, call_times)
, 0,
00999 (char*)"total runtime in each thunk"},
01000 {(char*)"position_of_error", T_INT, offsetof(CLazyLinker, position_o
f_error), 0,
01001 (char*)"position of failed thunk"},
01002 {(char*)"time_thunks", T_INT, offsetof(CLazyLinker, do_timing), 0,
01003 (char*)"bool: nonzero means call will time thunks"},
01004 {(char*)"need_update_inputs", T_INT, offsetof(CLazyLinker, need_upda
te_inputs), 0,
01005 (char*)"bool: nonzero means Function.call must implement update
mechanism"},
01006 {NULL} /* Sentinel */
01007 };
01008
01009 static PyTypeObject lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType = {
01010 #if defined(NPY_PY3K)
01011 PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
01012 #else
01013 PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
01014 0, /ob_size/
01015 #endif
01016 "lazylinker_ext.CLazyLinker", /tp_name/
01017 sizeof(CLazyLinker), /tp_basicsize/
01018 0, /tp_itemsize/
01019 CLazyLinker_dealloc, /tp_dealloc/
01020 0, /tp_print/
01021 0, /tp_getattr/
01022 0, /tp_setattr/
01023 0, /tp_compare/
01024 0, /tp_repr/
01025 0, /tp_as_number/
01026 0, /tp_as_sequence/
01027 0, /tp_as_mapping/
01028 0, /*tp_hash /
01029 CLazyLinker_call, /tp_call/
01030 0, /tp_str/
01031 0, /tp_getattro/
01032 0, /tp_setattro/
01033 0, /tp_as_buffer/
01034 Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT|Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /tp_flags/
01035 "CLazyLinker object", / tp_doc /
01036 0, / tp_traverse /
01037 0, / tp_clear /
01038 0, / tp_richcompare /
01039 0, / tp_weaklistoffset /
01040 0, / tp_iter /
01041 0, / tp_iternext /
01042 0,//CLazyLinker_methods, / tp_methods /
01043 CLazyLinker_members, / tp_members /
01044 CLazyLinker_getset, / tp_getset /
01045 0, / tp_base /
01046 0, / tp_dict /
01047 0, / tp_descr_get /
01048 0, / tp_descr_set /
01049 0, / tp_dictoffset /
01050 (initproc)CLazyLinker_init,/ tp_init /
01051 0, / tp_alloc /
01052 CLazyLinker_new, / tp_new */
01053 };
01054
01055 static PyObject * get_version(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args)
01056 {
01057 PyObject *result = PyFloat_FromDouble(0.211);
01058 return result;
01059 }
01060
01061 static PyMethodDef lazylinker_ext_methods[] = {
01062 {"get_version", get_version, METH_VARARGS, "Get extension version."},

01063 {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL} /* Sentinel /
01064 };
01065
01066 #if defined(NPY_PY3K)
01067 static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
01068 PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
01069 "lazylinker_ext",
01070 NULL,
01071 -1,
01072 lazylinker_ext_methods,
01073 NULL,
01074 NULL,
01075 NULL,
01076 NULL
01077 };
01078 #endif
01079 #if defined(NPY_PY3K)
01080 #define RETVAL m
01081 PyMODINIT_FUNC
01082 PyInit_lazylinker_ext(void) {
01083 #else
01084 #define RETVAL
01085 PyMODINIT_FUNC
01086 initlazylinker_ext(void)
01087 {
01088 #endif
01089 PyObject m;
01090
01091 lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
01092 if (PyType_Ready(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType) < 0)
01093 return RETVAL;
01094 #if defined(NPY_PY3K)
01095 m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
01096 #else
01097 m = Py_InitModule3("lazylinker_ext", lazylinker_ext_methods,
01098 "Example module that creates an extension type.")
;
01099 #endif
01100 Py_INCREF(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType);
01101 PyModule_AddObject(m, "CLazyLinker", (PyObject *)&lazylinker_ext_CLa
zyLinkerType);
01102
01103 return RETVAL;
01104 }
01105

Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
"C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -shared -g -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m
32 -I"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Progr
amData\Anaconda2\include" -I"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\g
of" -L"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\libs" -L"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2" -o C:\Users\R
abia Noureen\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-x86_Family_6
Model_42_Stepping_7_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-32\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:
\Users\Rabia Noureen\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-x86
Family_6_Model_42_Stepping_7_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -lpyt
hon27
g++.exe: error: Noureen\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-x
86_Family_6_Model_42_Stepping_7_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-32\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker
_ext.pyd: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: C:\Users\Rabia: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Noureen\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-x
86_Family_6_Model_42_Stepping_7_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp: N
o such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./tagger.py", line 8, in
from loader import prepare_sentence
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\tagger-master\tagger-master\loader.py", line 4,
in
from utils import create_dico, create_mapping, zero_digits
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\tagger-master\tagger-master\utils.py", line 5,
in
import theano
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano_init_.py", line 66,
in
from theano.compile import (
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile_init_.py",
line 10, in
from theano.compile.function_module import *
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_modul
e.py", line 21, in
import theano.compile.mode
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line
10, in
import theano.gof.vm
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 662,
in
from . import lazylinker_c
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py",
line 127, in
preargs=args)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line
2316, in compile_str
(status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): g++.exe: error: Noureen\AppData
\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-x86_Family_6_Model_42_Stepping_7
_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-32\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd: No such file or direc
. g++.exe: error: Noureen\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
-x86_Family_6_Model_42_Stepping_7_GenuineIntel-2.7.13-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:
. o such file or directory
```

Comment: perhaps this link can give you some hints:https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5803

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.